# SwiftUI VStack children with transition and matchedGeometryEffect ignore transition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having a very strange issue with SwiftUI animations. I have three views, one with image, second with image and text and third one which swaps them with animation.

```swift
struct FirstView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "clock.fill")
            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace)
            .imageScale(.large)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct SecondView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Text")
                .bold()
                .transition(
                    .asymmetric(
                        insertion: .move(edge: .top),
                        removal: .move(edge: .top)
                    )
                )
            
            Image(systemName: "clock.fill")
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "image", in: namespace)
                .imageScale(.large)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

```swift
struct SwitchView<FirstView: View, SecondView: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var firstView: () -> FirstView
    @ViewBuilder var secondView: () -> SecondView
    @Binding var switched: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if !switched {
                firstView()
            } else {
                secondView()
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I also have this TestView where I have SwitchView and a button for a binding

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State var switched = false
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            SwitchView(firstView: {
                FirstView(namespace: namespace)
            }, secondView: {
                SecondView(namespace: namespace)
            }, switched: $switched)
            
            Button("Switch") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                    switched.toggle()
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

With this configuration `transition` in the SecondView does not work. It also does not work if I remove an image all together. `VStack` is removing transition. I can move transition outside VStack, but then I won't have a desirable effect.

Anybody knows how to deal with this? The actual animation is below:

[image: Actual Result]

Comment: The transition modifier works (btw paired with animation) when modified view is inserted/removed from parent container, but in your code there is no such scenario - modified view (ie. Text) is a monolithic part of SecondView, which is inserted/removed as a whole. Think about this as like you draw SecondView into image and then insert this image instead of FirstView-image (in reality it is not exact that way but kind of).

Comment: @Asperi
So, if I want create a view where every of it's element has a different transition, I need to create them completely separately inside a `ZStack` with a very weird layout code?